# How to register a Squirrel class in C++

Tags: c++, squirrel

Hello I'm trying to make use of Squirrel within a C++ application.
For this reason I want to register a Squirrel class in C++.
Let's take the following class as an example.

```
class Foo
{
    constructor(value)
    {
        ::print("constructor called");
        this.testValue = value;
    }

    function saySomething()
    {
        ::print("The value is: " + this.testValue);
    }

    testValue = 0;
}
```

Can anybody please show me how to bind it in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it, by using [this code](http://sourceforge.net/p/scrat/wiki/Sqext/).

In my example it would look like this:

```
sqext::SQIClass testClass(L"Foo");
testClass.bind(0, L"testValue");
testClass.bind(1, L"saySomething");

sqext::SQIClassInstance test = testClass.New(4711);
test.call(1);
```